# How to make an array of class objects in Python (Numpy)

Tags: python, numpy

I have started to learn python and numpy,
I wanted to make an array of class objects.
I have checked google but i cant seem to find any article regarding this (atleast non that is easy to understand at my level)

This is some of my code that i am trying to execute if it helps

```
class Point:
    def __init(self):
        self.x = random()
        self.y = random()
    def show(self):
        .
        .
        (function code)
        .
        .


points = np.empty(100, dtype = Point)
for i in range(100):
    points[i].show()
```

traceback

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'
```

The c++ analogue would be

```
Point = points[100];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    points[i].show()
}
```

I want to implement this in python so I can use the show() that I have defined in the class
Please guide me if I have not given enough information (also new to stacksoverflow)
thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Maybe `points = [Point() for _ in range(100]` will help

Comment: For a beginning Python/numpy coder, this is not a good start.  It's one thing to define a class, and put multiple instances in a list.  But don't try to make an array from them.   It doesn't add much, either in terms of expressiveness or performance.   Learn to use the numeric `numpy` code well first.

Comment: @hpaulj do you know if SIMD operations are supported for arrays of objects?  I've never seen this done anywhere

Comment: @anon01, like a `list`, an `object` dtype array contains references (pointers) to objects stored else where in memory.  To access an attribute or run a method, you have to get the reference to that object - that's a pure Python operation.  Iteration on an object dtype array is a bit slower than iteration on a list.

Comment: Did you try checking the value of `points`?

Comment: Numpy and objects don't really mix that well.  Typically, a Point is just a dimension inside a matrix of size 2.  So I would write `np.zeros((100, 2))`.

Comment: As @ShivamJha suggests, you have to call `Point()` once for each element you want to create.  There's no short cut.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
points = np.empty(100, dtype = Point)
```

It is just saying that the data type of the things inside `points` is `Point`. It is not filling `points` with objects. You need to put objects inside it explicitly. One way would be

```
points[0] = Point()
```

And so on.

Comment: Actually it's `dtype=object`.  The elements are references to any kind of python object.  Here, for safety, they are all set to `None`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. That was surprising. I need to understand why it is `dtype=object` and not `dtype=Point`

Comment: If the `dtype` isn't a builtin 'scalar' (`np.int64`, `U3` etc), or compound (structured array), it is `object`.  Just as with a `list`, such an array holds references to python objects, which can be anything - `None`, `list`, number, array, user-defined class, etc.